# addTo* not persisting changes

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.3

I'm using the grails console to play with my relationships. I'm using the excersises on the book `Grails in Action`:

I have the relationship:

```
class User {
    ...

    Profile profile 

    static hasMany = [posts: Post, tags: Tag, following: User]

        ...


User.get(3).addToFollowing( User.get(2) ).save()    
User.list().each { print it.following   }
```

yields

> null null [com.grailsinaction.User : 2] null null

and again running:

```
User.get(1).addToFollowing( User.get(2) ).save()    
User.list().each { print it.following   }
```

gives

> [com.grailsinaction.User : 2] null null null null

Looks like the first `addToFollowing` is lost... did I forget anything?

Comment: By default grails uses h2 database, on each app. run database dropped and created fresh one. If you had restarted your application previous entry will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
User.get(3).addToFollowing( User.get(2) ).save(flush: true)
```

**The object will not be persisted immediately unless the flush argument is used.** See related [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html).